# How to get rid of black edges from XYZ function mesh?

Tags: mesh

Blender newbie here. I used XYZ function in the add-ons to generate several meshes. Right now, the meshes are dense with black edges. How do I get these edges to be invisible when the object is not selected? For example, the UV sphere at the bottom looks lovely.

[image: Picture of mesh with black lines]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the meshes generated by this operator have *Wireframe Display* enabled in the viewport.

If you have already generated the mesh :

Go the object properties > Viewport Display > Uncheck *Wireframe*

[image]

If you just created the mesh using the operator, look into the lower left, you can expand a panel or use the shortcut <kbd>F9</kbd>, then look into the lower part of the panel. Uncheck "Show Wireframe".

[image]

Note 1 : This setting will be remembered in the current Blender session.

Note 2 : If you want to change the behaviour for all sessions, go to your blender install folder and then *2.*** / scripts / addons / add_mesh_extra_objects and open add_mesh_3d_function_surface.py (use notepad)

Search for "AddXYZFunctionSurface" class in the file, go down to the lines

```
show_wire : BoolProperty(
        name="Show wireframe",
        default=True,
        description="Add the object’s wireframe over solid drawing"
        )
```

500 to 504 in my file, and replace

```
    default=True,
```

with

```
    default=False,
```

Save the file, close it, open blender, the setting will be set to False by default.

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly.